# The the value of 'a' for which $f$ is onto.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

f: $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow$(6,$\infty$) , $f(x) = x^{2} -(a-3)x
+a+6,$ then the value of 'a' for which function is onto

(a) $(1,9)$

(b) $[1,9]$

(c) $\{1,9\}$

(d) None of these

$\boldsymbol{My}$$\boldsymbol{Approach}$$\Longrightarrow$ Using
hit and trial method I can say (d) is correct.

$\boldsymbol{My}$$\boldsymbol{Question}$$\Longrightarrow$What is
the proper algebraic way to tackle these kind of question.??

If using Hit andd trial is ideal method ??

$\boldsymbol{Hit}$$\boldsymbol{And}$ $\boldsymbol{Trial\Longrightarrow}$Taking
the values of a from the options and calculating the f(x) and predicting
the answer on behalf of these results.

Comment: So what is it's minimum?

Comment: @Vim minimum value of 'a' should be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If function $f$ is onto then $(6,\infty)$ must be its image.

But does there exist any quadratic function with this image?

No, hence d) is the correct answer here.

The image of a quadratic function has shape $[c,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,c]$ where $c\in\mathbb R$ denotes a constant.

Can you find out why yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the following equation:
$$f\left(\frac{a-3}{2}\right)=6,$$
but in all case you'll get $[6,+\infty)$, which says that the answer is $(d)$.

Comment: but how  can we fix the x at some value when the function is supposed to be onto for whatever x we may choose.

Comment: @Kislay Tripathi Because your $f$ works so $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow[k,+\infty)$ for some real $k$. If you wish to get $(6,+\infty)$ then it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As $f(x)$ opens upward, it suffices to find $a$ such that the minimum of the function is $6$, i.e. $f(x)=6$ has root.

$x^2-(a-3)x+a+6=6$

$x^2-(a-3)x+a=0$

$\Delta=(a-3)^2-4a = a^2-10a+9 = (a-1)(a-9) \ge 0$

Therefore, $a \le 1$ or $a \ge 9$. Rejecting $a<1$ and $a>9$ gives us (c).

[Note that your question is bs as $f$ isn't even a function when $a=0$]

Comment: But $6\notin(6,\infty)$.

Comment: What's the evidence for your last statement "f isn't a function"?